# I need to get highest number of item in following table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wrote the following T-SQL query to select count value of a particular table.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Item1) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item1 AS ITEM
FROM 
    [cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
     [Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY 
     Item1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    COUNT(Item2) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item2 AS ITEM
FROM 
    [cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
    [Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY  
    Item2
ORDER BY 
    ITEM_COUNT DESC
```

And I get the following results:

```
ITEM_COUNT  ITEM
-------------------------
7           Tommy
5           Denim shorts
4           Boxers
3           Diesel_D
3           Emerald
3           Jockey
2           Polo_D
2           Polo_D
2           Tommy
2           Gucci
```

I need to get highest number of item record in above result table. For example there is 7 number of "Tommy" in first row and 2 number of "Tommy" 9th row. So altogether there is 9 number of "Tommy" which is highest in above result.

How do I need to change the above query to get this result?

Comment: just group by `Item1` instead of `Item2`

Comment: can you explain little a bit further plaese?

Comment: well....your query has a `GROUP BY Item2`, and you need to change it to `GROUP BY Item1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 * from ( select sum(item_count) as total, item from (
SELECT 
COUNT(Item1) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item1 AS ITEM
FROM 
[cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
 [Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY 
 Item1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
COUNT(Item2) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item2 AS ITEM
FROM 
[cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
[Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY  
Item2
ORDER BY 
ITEM_COUNT DESC

) group by item order by total desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for each ITEM, you only want to see one row (with the largest count), but if you can provide us with sample data, we can figure out better. But assume my understanding is correct, the following code should work for you

```
with c as (
SELECT 
    COUNT(Item1) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item1 AS ITEM
FROM 
    [cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
     [Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY 
     Item1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    COUNT(Item2) AS ITEM_COUNT, Item2 AS ITEM
FROM 
    [cloths_DB].[dbo].[Suggetion_DB]
WHERE 
    [Type] = 'Dockers' and [Age] = '25'
GROUP BY  
    Item2
)
, c2 as (
          select item_count, item
         , rnk=row_number() over (partition by Item order by item_count desc)
         from c
        )
select item_count, item from c2 
where rnk = 1;
```